# Using a C++ class in C code

Tags: c

I was under the impression that it should be possible to mix c and c++ code, but looks like I was wrong.

I'm having a bunch of existing C code and have written a class in C++ that I would like to use in the existing C code.

Is that even possible?

Comment: how about compile everything as C++

Comment: You have to write a wrapper around your C++ class that will be accessible from C. This usually means creating a wrapper `struct` that has a pointer to the C++ instance of a class, and a function for each class member function that takes this wrapper `struct` and calls the C++ member function from C++ code.

Comment: Note that while you can compile it as C++, mixing C and C++ rarely results in quality code. They are different languages and should be treated as such.

Comment: Even if you wrap the C++ class, you still have to be pretty careful, since if you compile your `main()` function as C then constructors aren't going to be run on static instances, for instance, and depending on what facilities your C++ class uses, you might not even know that you're using some of these.

Answer (score 2):

`C++` is not a superset of `C` and thus not all `C` code is valid `C++` code. This is even more true for `C++` code in a `C` compiler. All language additions `C++` has are not valid `C` (classes, generic programming, namespaces). What you could do is compile the result code with a `C++` compiler and fix cases where code that was valid for a `C` compiler isn't for a `C++` compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use classes from C code, because classes don't exist in C.

However, you can define a bunch of *global functions* that access your class, and then you can access those functions from C.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the two and then compile the result as C++.

If you have a C++ class that you want to use in C then you could remove all the member functions and rewrite then with an extra parameter being a ptr to a structure.
More advance C++ features wouldn't be so easy to incorporate in C.

Comment: You cannot compile C as C++. If you do that, you never wrote C code, you wrote C++ code. Please do not confuse these two languages.